# Uber API synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: api, synchronous, uber-api

does the uber deliveries api use synchronous or asynchronous calls? I see it says that both work for uber rides. just wondering if deliveries is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deliveries api is synchronous.

Comment: thanks dustin. another quick question. do you ever pass along the driver info and lat/long?

In the delivery response all i see is "carrier:null". Is there a way to get the drivers info and location?

Comment: See the get deliveries endpoint. Once they have picked up the package you can track it: https://developer.uber.com/docs/deliveries/references/api/v1/deliveries-delivery_id-get